# Convert info from Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I would like to extract information from an Excel file and paste the information in PowerPoint.

Below you can see the updated code where someone here helped me with this issue.

What I want for now:

1. Change the specific file location, where I can give the user the possibility to choose where is the file to be edited by my macro.
2. Include an option with a bottom selection option where the user can
   (a) save the file only;
   (b) save the file in a directory chosen by them.
   (c) send it by Microsoft Outlook.

Code without the feature to select the file:

```vb
Sub PasteExcelDataIntoPowerPointTextbox()
    Dim ppApp As Object
    Dim ppSlide As Object
    Dim ppTextBox As Object
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim excelRange As Excel.Range
    
    ' Initialize PowerPoint and Excel
    Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    ppApp.Visible = True ' Make PowerPoint visible
       
    ' Open the PowerPoint presentation
    Set ppPresentation = ppApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\Public\HiringResultsNew.pptx")
       
    ' Assuming the Excel file is already open, else you can open it too
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
    Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets("HiringResults") ' Change to your sheet name
    
    ' Get the range of Excel data you want to copy
    Dim arrCell, arrShp, i as Long
    arrCell=Array("C1","C2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8","D9","D10","D11","D12","D13","D14","D15","D16","D17","D18","D19","D20","D21")
    arrShp=Array("REFTYPE","REFBUSINESS","REFNUMBERFILLS","REFVARIATION","REFTTF","REFCNPS","REFHMNPS","REFACTREQ","REFDIVMALE","REFDIVFAME","REFHIREINT","REFHIREEXT","REFTSTASO","REFTSEMRE","REFTSAGENC","REFLEVEX","REFLEVDI","REFLEVMA","REFLEVIN","REFDATAREF","REFKEYINSIGHTS")

    Set ppSlide = ppPresentation.Slides(1)
    For i = LBound(arrCell) To UBound(arrCell)
        Set excelRange = xlWorksheet.Range(arrCell(i))
        Set ppTextBox = ppSlide.Shapes(arrShp(i)).TextFrame.TextRange
        ppTextBox.Text = excelRange.Text
    Next

    ' Clean up
    Set ppApp = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWorkbook = Nothing
    Set xlWorksheet = Nothing
    Set ppPresentation = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Report completed. Please edit and save it."
 
End Sub
```

I want to include the option where the user can select the file by their own, using the code mentioned below:

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim obiFileDialog As FileDialog, strFilePath As String
    Set obiFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    obiFileDialog.Title = "Select PowerPoint File"
    obiFileDialog.Filters.Clear
    obiFileDialog.Filters.Add "PowerPoint Files", "*.ppt*"
    obiFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If obiFileDialog.Show Then
        strFilePath = obiFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        MsgBox "Your file is " & strFilePath
        ' Your code to open pptx
    End If
End Sub
```

I have another question:
My concern is that different users will access it, due to the information  privileged, so the ideal scenario would be a place where no one would be able to access it, as it has been now in the C:\Users\Public\HiringResultsNew.pptx.

Comment: Writing in all upper-case is considered shouting. And it's very rude to shout at the people you want to help you. Please [edit] your question to stop shouting.

Comment: If `no one would be able to access it`, then how can you access it? Is it the same question as your last comments which is under my answer?

Comment: The ideia is that the VBA code consider the current file where both files are located in. I would like to understand if we have this possibility- not to mention the origin of the file, but consider the current folder that the user is suing at the moment. With this option, they can save the excel and the ppt at the same folder, and the macro identify it. Do you consider it possible?

Comment: I also got your update but I don’t now how to include it in the body of the code as well

Comment: Check the code which is marked with `**change**`.

Answer (score 0):

- Using loop to simplify the code
- Using `Text` property of TextBoxes to update its content

```
Sub PasteExcelDataIntoPowerPointTextbox()
    Dim ppApp As Object
    Dim ppSlide As Object
    Dim ppTextBox As Object
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim excelRange As Excel.Range
    
    ' Initialize PowerPoint and Excel
    Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    ppApp.Visible = True ' Make PowerPoint visible
       
    ' Open the PowerPoint presentation
    ' Set ppPresentation = ppApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\Public\HiringResultsNew.pptx")
    
    ' If both Excel and PPT are in the same folder
    Set ppPresentation = ppApp.Presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\HiringResultsNew.pptx")   '**change**
    ' Assuming the Excel file is already open, else you can open it too
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
    Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets("HiringResults") ' Change to your sheet name
    
    ' Get the range of Excel data you want to copy
    Dim arrCell, arrShp, i as Long
    arrCell=Array("C1","C2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8","D9","D10","D11","D12","D13","D14","D15","D16","D17","D18","D19","D20","D21")
    arrShp=Array("REFTYPE","REFBUSINESS","REFNUMBERFILLS","REFVARIATION","REFTTF","REFCNPS","REFHMNPS","REFACTREQ","REFDIVMALE","REFDIVFAME","REFHIREINT","REFHIREEXT","REFTSTASO","REFTSEMRE","REFTSAGENC","REFLEVEX","REFLEVDI","REFLEVMA","REFLEVIN","REFDATAREF","REFKEYINSIGHTS")

    Set ppSlide = ppPresentation.Slides(1)
    For i = LBound(arrCell) To UBound(arrCell)
        Set excelRange = xlWorksheet.Range(arrCell(i))
        Set ppTextBox = ppSlide.Shapes(arrShp(i)).TextFrame.TextRange
        ppTextBox.Text = excelRange.Text
    Next
       
    ' Clean up
    Set ppApp = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWorkbook = Nothing
    Set xlWorksheet = Nothing
    Set ppPresentation = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Report completed. Please edit and save it."
 
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Workbook.Path property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.path?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm199121)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

---

Update:

> Question: is it possible to change the file location? I mean: instead of this macro open the file from "C:\users...", the macro gives the option to the user to select the file location?

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim obiFileDialog As FileDialog, strFilePath As String
    Set obiFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    obiFileDialog.Title = "Select PowerPoint File"
    obiFileDialog.Filters.Clear
    obiFileDialog.Filters.Add "PowerPoint Files", "*.ppt*"
    obiFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If obiFileDialog.Show Then
        strFilePath = obiFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        MsgBox "Your file is " & strFilePath
        ' Your code to open pptx
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [FileDialog object (Office)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Do I have to include anything else in the begining of the code or just modify for this?

Comment: I have updated it with full code.

Comment: I will updated it and let you know! Many thanks.

Comment: Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets("HiringResults") ' in this line there is a error  runtime error -9 subscript out of range. How to solve it?

Comment: It worked, but I am wondering why I found the error -9 in the first time that I was executing the macro.

Comment: It comes from you code. I haven't revised it. Error 9 means can't find sheet `HiringResults`. Make sure the workbook (`xlWorkbook`) is opened.

Comment: A question: is it possible to change the file location? I mean: instead of this macro open the file from "C:\users...", the macro gives the option to the user to select the file location?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Taller, I am sorry foir bothering you. Where can I include this code? After which line, exactly? I ask you because I have no previous experiences with VBA and I want to create something fine. Your efforts your truly appreciated by me.

Comment: [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: I am new in the community and I am learning how to interact here. Many thanks for your previous support. I updated my questions here.