# Excel VBA has been removing information from my text box instead of insert information from excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

When I execute my macro below, instead of my PowerPoint receive and past information from specific cells in Excel to PowerPoint, my macro clears the information in powerpoint.

```
Sub PasteExcelDataIntoPowerPointTextbox()
    Dim ppApp As Object
    Dim ppSlide As Object
    Dim ppTextBox As Object
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim excelRange As Excel.Range
    
    ' Initialize PowerPoint and Excel
    Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    ppApp.Visible = True ' Make PowerPoint visible
       
    ' Open the PowerPoint presentation
    ' Set ppPresentation = ppApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\Public\HiringResultsNew.pptx")
    
    ' If both Excel and PPT are in the same folder
    Set ppPresentation = ppApp.Presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\HiringResultsNew.pptx")   
    ' Assuming the Excel file is already open, else you can open it too
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
    Set xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets("HiringResults") ' Change to your sheet name
    
    ' Get the range of Excel data you want to copy
    Dim arrCell, arrShp, i As Long
    arrCell = Array("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D12", "D13", "D14", "D15", "D16", "D17", "D18", "D19", "D20", "D21")
    arrShp = Array("REFTYPE", "REFBUSINESS", "REFNUMBERFILLS", "REFVARIATION", "REFTTF", "REFCNPS", "REFHMNPS", "REFACTREQ", "REFDIVMALE", "REFDIVFAME", "REFHIREINT", "REFHIREEXT", "REFTSTASO", "REFTSEMRE", "REFTSAGENC", "REFLEVEX", "REFLEVDI", "REFLEVMA", "REFLEVIN", "REFDATAREF", "REFKEYINSIGHTS")

    Set ppSlide = ppPresentation.Slides(1)
    For i = LBound(arrCell) To UBound(arrCell)
        Set excelRange = xlWorksheet.Range(arrCell(i))
        Set ppTextBox = ppSlide.Shapes(arrShp(i)).TextFrame.TextRange
        ppTextBox.Text = excelRange.Text
    Next
       
    ' Clean up
    Set ppApp = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWorkbook = Nothing
    Set xlWorksheet = Nothing
    Set ppPresentation = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Report completed. Please edit and save it."
 
End Sub
```

Original post: [Convert info from Excel to ppt- specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77476145/convert-info-from-excel-to-ppt-specific-fields)

I started with a basic code without knowledge, but someone nice helped me to create the looping instead of copying and pasting code from each cell. I executed it and it worked right, but I made some changes in my file, including other information (not related to the macro) and now when I click in the bottom to execute it, it does not open automatically and also I have to click on F5 to start the process.

Comment: Try to replace the workbook assignment with the name of the workbook. `Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks("workbook.name")` as it is displayed in the window title.

Comment: My looping is working right, but they are not collecting the information from my excel file and the error is the same: it finishes the report with the message box, but zero content in the powerpoint file. Where exactly do I have to change the information you provided? I am asking you because I don't have previous experiences with VBA. could you please show me the code that I have to change?

Comment: After the `GetObject` , the line which starts with `Set xlWorkbook`

Comment: Change the line to `ppTextBox.Text = excelRange.Address(1,1,xlA1,True)` to confirm correct sheet and range.

Comment: It should be like:    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks("workbook.HiringResults"), correct? For me there is an error indicateing that subscript is out of range.

Comment: @CDP1802 which line you mean?

Comment: Change the existing line `ppTextBox.Text = excelRange.Text`. To set workbook try  `Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks("HiringResults") ` You may need to add file extension  .xlsx or .xlsm

Comment: @CDP1802 I included both and now I found another error in the line        Set excelRange = xlWorksheet.Range(arrCell(i))   - error says: Object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: Comment out that line with error and change the `ppTextBox.Text` line to `ppTextBox.Text = arrCell(i)`, The text boxes should fill with D1, D2, D3 etc

Comment: No. Type only the workbook name and extension (as seen in the Excel window title) where the `HiringResult` sheet is.